# jQuery load() function inserts non-interpreted code

Tags: php, jquery, function, load, alert

I try to put a piece of code from a php file into my index.php file using jquery.
I use the function `load()` of jQuery to do that, and I have no problem with that.

The problem is that this piece of code is not interpreted properly. In this example, I import an `span`, and to see if this span is properly imported in the index.php, I'm using the `jQuery click` function

The php code that I want to import

```
//myText.php

<?php
    echo '<span>theSpan</span>';
?>
```

Then the jQuery code

```
//scripts.js

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".my-php").load("myText.php");

    $("span").click(function(){
        alert( "Success : it's a span !" );
    });

});
```

The php of index.php

```
//index.php

<body>
    <div class="my-php">
    </div>
</body>
```

So, when I click on the span that is inside the my-php div, I'm supposed to see `"Success : it's a span"`. But nothing happens. The span is here with the text `'theSpan'` but when I click on it, nothing happens.

I tried something to fix that, but it's a really strange behaviour.
I change the jQuery code to that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var StrPhp = 'test';
    alert("1 - StrPhp : " +StrPhp); //Return 'test'

    $(".my-php").load("myBets.php", function(str){
        StrPhp = str;
        alert("2 - StrPhp : " +StrPhp); //Return '<span>theSpan</span>'
    });

    $(".my-php").html(StrPhp);

});
```

So, I initialize a variable StrPhp with `'test'`.
I try to catch the callback of the `load function` with `StrPhp = str`.
And then I try to put in the my-php div with `html function`.
It didn't work. The span is here with the text `'theSpan'` but when I click, nothing.

BUT !!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var StrPhp = 'test';
    alert("1 - StrPhp : " +StrPhp); //Return 'test'

    $(".my-php").load("myBets.php", function(str){
        StrPhp = str;
        alert("2 - StrPhp : " +StrPhp); //Return '<span>theSpan</span>'
    });

    alert("3 - StrPhp : " +StrPhp); //Return 'test'
    alert("4 - StrPhp : " +StrPhp); //Return '<span>theSpan</span>' !!!
    $(".my-php").html(StrPhp);

});
```

With two alerts before the `html() function`, it works !
The span in into the my-php div, and is interpreted. I mean when I click on it, I can see `"Success : it's a span"`.
Without these alerts, the span is not interpreted by jQuery and when I click, nothing happens.

Obviously, this is not fixed because using alerts is not something I want to do everytime I have this problem.

So if someone can help me, it will be appreciated !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: tl;dr: the `load()` function is asynchronous

Comment: Can't bind events to elements that don't exist at the time your code runs. Either delegate the events or run the code when the elements do exist

Comment: in other words when you tell the pro... what ^he says

Answer (score 2):

Use the [complete](https://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete) parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".my-php").load("myText.php",function () {
     $("span").click(function(){
       alert( "Success : it's a span !" );
     })
   });
});
```

Comment: Obviously, the final use of this load in not this Click function, but a lot of operations that shouldn't be in this Load. It was just a test

Comment: @user2488028 then provide more real world code in your examples. We don't have crystal balls to guess what you are trying to do

Comment: @charlietfl I was saying that to say : if I have a lot of click function or others functions, I have to duplicate all in this load ?

Comment: @user2488028 no, you can use event delegation  https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".my-php").load("myText.php");
    $(".my-php").on('click','span',function(){
                    alert( "Success : it's a span !" );
                });

});
```